# Not able to manipulate the image after uploading it on Telegram

Tags: image-processing, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm trying to build a telegram bot for resizing image. I'm using Python for coding and using the pyTelegramBotAPI as the wrapper. The issue that I'm facing is that I'm not able to manipulate the image after I upload it on Telegram. I'm trying to use Pillow module for image manipulation. As fas as I understand as of now, the bot API is providing the "file ID" of the image instead of the image itself, due to which the Pillow module is not able to do anything about it. Here's the function that I've written so far:

```
    # Handles all sent image files
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def image_resize(message):
  sent_photo = message.photo[-1].file_id
  bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Enter the desired dimensions (WIDTHxHEIGHT), for example 300x150.")
  @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
  def resize(message):
    width, height = message.text.split("x")
    im = Image.open(sent_photo)
    resized_img = im.resize((width, height))
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, resized_img)
```

The error that I'm getting:

> im = Image.open(sent_photo)
> File "/home/runner/imageResizertb/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 3068, in open
> fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'AgACAgUAAxkBAANyYnk0JGdGDY1_NbbYlfiYamTyrYMAAtmwMRvHg8lXDixv48nY6SYBAAMCAAN5AAMkBA'

Can anybody help me understanding how the API is handling the image file and how to manipulate it?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the File/Image ID to pillow. You'll need to save the file name somewhere or download the file into memory as such:

```
from io import BytesIO

 @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
 def resize(message):
    file = bot.get_file(sent_photo)
    download_file = bot.download_file(file.file_path)
    f = BytesIO(download_file)
    im = Image.open(f)
    resized_img = im.resize((width, height))
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, resized_img)
```

Comment: I've implemented this piece of code. I'm now getting the following error:

File "main.py", line 27, in resize
    f = BytesIO(file.download_as_bytearray())
AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'download_as_bytearray'

Comment: I've edited my answer. I thought pyTelegramBotAPI has the same functions as python-telegram-bot. It should work now.